# ignore specific js files in chrome dev tools when debugging

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to ignore certain javascript files when debugging with breakpoints in Chrome Developer Tools? Let's say on this website http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/#/ I want to debug only todoCtrl.js and ignore all other ones like angular.js.

Comment: I'm upvoting this *as hard as I can*

Comment: It seems like they removed it. You need to enter the scripts manually in the settings. It used to work by right clicking on the script and ignore it

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/ignore-list

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use JS Blackboxing to do this. The documentation for this feature will be going live soon, but for now you can read the WIP doc on how to do this here:

https://rawgit.com/jaredwilli/devtools-docs/blackboxing/docs/blackboxing.html

Comment: [Updated link for Blackboxing](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code#blackbox_third-party_code) from [developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE).google.com (click the first link in this comment, not the second)

Comment: am I the only one who thinks whitelisting would make a lot more sense?