# Is it possible to hide JavaScript framework call stacks when debugging, only step over application JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

I got assigned working on a front-end project written in a mvc frontend framework, every time when I try to debug the code base to better understand the application logic, I got sucked in to the framework code, for now, I don't really want to dig into the framework implementation, but only focus on the application logic. Here's my question: is it possible to hide those framework call stacks? Or somehow only step over the application call stacks and skip the framework call stacks automatically?

BTW, I'm using chrome devtools and webstorm IDE.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can "step return" out of those things when you find yourself in them, and "step over" to avoid getting down there. You debugger should have those two buttons.

Comment: the framework script also is just some javascript like the script you have so the debugger don't have a way to know which are yours and which belongs to some framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome has an "manage framework blackboxing" option available under the "sources" section of the settings page you access through the gear icon in devtools. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing) for more details. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When you click it, you are able to designate libraries to "blackbox":

[image]

Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278135/chrome-devtools-script-blackboxing-not-working), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068448/ignore-specific-js-files-in-chrome-dev-tools-when-debugging).

Comment: torazahuro, you're the god to me !